# Create Column in Data Frame that Indicates Repeated Value in Another Column

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique

Say I have a data table like this in R:

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNZEj.jpg)

And I want to a add column to this table which indicates if the person switched majors (like "Y" for switched, "N" for didn't switch), how would I do that? I've tried using the count and unique functions but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: How do you know if major is switched? If the `ID` has only one entry then it is not switched?

Comment: If the ID repeats further down the table, then the major was switched

Comment: One way to solve this is by using `ave` and `ifelse`: `ifelse(ave(df$Major, df$ID, FUN = length) > 1, "Y", "N")`. Also instead of posting images try to give `dput()` of your dataframe which might be helpful for others to help you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `ave` and `max(seq_along(ID))>1`.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but your solution gave me a vector of just "Y"s. 42, thank you but your idea returned an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a column `IsSwitched` by using `by` clause of `data.table`:

```
DT[, IsSwitched:= ifelse(.N>1,"Y","N"), by=Id]
```

Where `DT` is your data.table.